# How do I tell when a client disconnects from a Web Socket using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have a Node websocket and I am trying to detect when a client disconnects. I tried the following code per the docs but I still can't detect the closing...

```
        const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
            server: this.server
        });
        this.wss = wss;
        this.wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
            Logger.log("verbose", `Web socket is now alive`);
            ws.isAlive = true;
            ws.on("pong", function(){
                Logger.log("verbose", `Web socket pong`);
                console.log(`the pong is ${this.isAlive} ${ws.isAlive}`);
                this.isAlive = true;
            });
        });
        setInterval(()=>{
            console.log(`Setting the interval ${wss.clients.length}`);
            wss.clients.forEach(function each(ws) {
                if (ws.isAlive === false){
                    Logger.log("verbose", `The web socket died`);
                    return ws.terminate();
                }
                ws.isAlive = false;
                ws.ping(()=>{});
            });
        }, 30000);
```

However, it seems that wss.clients is empty before it can be detected. How do I detect the connection actually closing?

### Update

Also tried the close event and the onclose function none seem to do what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a `ws.on("close", function close() {...})` inside of your `this.wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {...})`. As per your code:

```js
        const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
            server: this.server
        });
        this.wss = wss;
        this.wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
            Logger.log("verbose", `Web socket is now alive`);
            ws.isAlive = true;
            ws.on("pong", function(){
                Logger.log("verbose", `Web socket pong`);
                console.log(`the pong is ${this.isAlive} ${ws.isAlive}`);
                this.isAlive = true;
            });
            ws.on("close", function() {
                //do closing stuff here
            });
        });
        setInterval(()=>{
            console.log(`Setting the interval ${wss.clients.length}`);
            wss.clients.forEach(function each(ws) {
                if (ws.isAlive === false){
                    Logger.log("verbose", `The web socket died`);
                    return ws.terminate();
                }
                ws.isAlive = false;
                ws.ping(()=>{});
            });
        }, 30000);
```

Comment: So this works in this case but when I pass the object and try to do it in another context it seems to be giving me trouble. I will try to give an example and open another question.

Comment: If you have multiple connections on the server, how do you know which connection closes?